# Run method from different scope

Tags: c#

I know that what i need help with is not called the Parent but that was the closest word i could think of to describe this situation.

This is not actual code i'm using.

I have `MainClass` which contains object `ObjectA`.

```
class MainClass
{
    public int mode = 0;
    ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();

}
```

I need to access the `mode` variable from the `ObjectA` object. Is this possible? I feel like if i could at least call a method in `MainClass` from `obj` i would be all set. Also I'm aware calling `MainClass` a parent in this sense is incorrect, what is the correct term for both the `MainClass` and `obj` in this.

Comment: I would also search this if i could but i don't know the terms necessary to search so thank you to whoever helps!

Comment: I assume you are allowed to change `ObjectA`?

Comment: The programming concept you're looking for is called "scope". I'd recommend reviewing the concept first and then focusing on variable and method scope in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the term. I am allowed to change ObjectA. I am going to see if its possible to use events or some other system as I need to run a method as very specific times. If not ill find another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are able to change `MainClass`, I can think of two options:

- Add a reference to `MainClass` when you create an `ObjectA` instance.
- Like you said in your comments, use events.

**Using a reference:**

```
class MainClass
{
    public int mode = 31416;
    ObjectA obj;

    public MainClass() 
    {
        obj = new ObjectA(this);
    }

    public int GetMainClassMode() 
    {
        return mode;
    }

    public void Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling test method inside obj");
        obj.Test();
    }
}

class ObjectA {

    MainClass parent = null;

    public ObjectA(MainClass parent) 
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void Test() 
    {
        if (parent != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting mode from 'parent' MainClass");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Mode = {0}", parent.GetMainClassMode()));
        }
    }       
}
```

---

**Using events:**

```
class MainClass
{
    public int mode = 31416;
    ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();


    public MainClass() 
    {
        obj.ValueReturnEvent += HandleValueReturnEvent;
    }

    public int GetMainClassMode() 
    {
        return mode;
    }

    // Handle event, return data
    private int HandleValueReturnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return mode;
    }

    public void Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling test method inside obj");
        obj.Test();
    }
}

class ObjectA {

    // delegate
    public delegate int ReturnValueEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    // event
    public event ReturnValueEventHandler ValueReturnEvent;


    public void Test() 
    {
        // make sure at least one subscriber
        if (ValueReturnEvent != null)  
        {
            // note the event is returning a value
            var myValue = ValueReturnEvent(this, null);

            Console.WriteLine("Getting mode from 'parent' MainClass");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Mode = {0}", myValue));
        }
    }   
}
```

---

On both cases, you get this output:

```
Calling test method inside obj
Getting mode from 'parent' MainClass
Mode = 31416
```

Comment: thank you I thought it was possible with events but had no idea how to implement. Thanks a whole bunch!

Comment: @iglooJuan great code, but looks little bit overengineered)))

Comment: @VadimSentyaev probably is, but very educational never the less. for anyone else who stumbles across it, they can take it and use it for other purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wire things up to let the child know about the parent for this to work.  Something like this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public int mode = 0;

    public ChildClass child = null;

    public ParentClass()
    {
        child = new ChildClass(this);
    }
}

class ChildClass 
{
    public readonly ParentClass parent = null;

    public ChildClass (ParentClass parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int MethodThatReadsParentMode()
    {
        int mode = parent.mode;
        return mode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've got your answer, you could also simply inject it into your `ObjectA` ... have a constructor that takes an int, and when you create the object pass the `mode` in and save it in that object.

I find it cleaner that the object uses whatever it needs from its scope, rather than accessing the parent to ask for a variable.
I'm not saying it might not be needed, it just another thought.

Answer (score -1):

You make field `mode` public, so I assume it's possible that someone who uses class `MainClass` do can change this field.

Let's assume program looks like this.

```
class Program {
  var main = new MainClass();
  main.mode = 1;
}
```

Your `obj` field is private, so `Program` cannot access it.
So, when someone changed field `mode`, `ObjectA` should get new value of field `mode`. 
Possible solution:

```
class ObjectA {
  public int Mode { get; set; }
}

class MainClass {
  private obj = new ObjectA();
  public int Mode {
    get { return this.obj.Mode; }
    set { this.obj.Mode = value; }
  }
}
```

There is another option in case field `mode` belongs to `MainCalss`.

```
class ObjectA {
  private int mode;
  public ObjectA(int mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
  }
  // you can create property instead of method
  // I'm not sure how you use this variable, so I just added set method
  public void SetMode(int mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
  }
}

class MainClass {
  private int mode = 0;
  private obj = new ObjectA();
  public int Mode {
    get { return this.mode; }
    set {
      this.obj.SetMode(value);
      this.mode = value; 
    }
  }
}
```